# PHP script usage monitoring

Tags: php

I would wish to know if it's possible to monitor (live or not live) system resources usage of php scripts?

Let's say I have huge site, and sometimes my CPU usage and RAM goes to 100 percent when normally it's 5-10 percent.

is it possible to monitor which exact script is doing this? or if not then maybe it's possible to know if that is done by checksomething.php and not site.php?

Comment: I cannot answer your question on how we track using "Code", but do you have image resize on the fly? Do you have heavy traffic on website, do you host with Shared hosting. If so, don't blame one script :). and give more detail so I Can help you find culprit...

Comment: Does your PHP script communicate with a database? In my experience, when RAM and CPU jump that high, it's a MySQL query hanging! You can certainly investigate that problem if you have shell access.

Comment: oh, sorry here are more details:

VPS with DirectAdmin installed
connection with the DB is fine
it's not fault of too many users, since it's beta testing site, and what is going is sometimes some internals of the (HUGE) script is slowing down whole server and I want to know which exact file or something like that is doing this.